# How to choose which storyboard to run on click of a Radio Button and Next button?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, binding

I am looking for the code which will allow running a certain storyboard based on which radio button is selected. The scenario is to select a radio button first and then click ‘Next” button to run storyboard. For example, if the first radio button is selected and “Next’ button clicked, then the first storyboard should be played. Any ideas are highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

XAML:

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
x:Class="ClickCount.MainWindow"
x:Name="Window"
Title="MainWindow"
Width="640" Height="480">
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard1">
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red"/>
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="#FF00FFED"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard2">
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red"/>
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="#FF5AFF00"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard3">
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red"/>
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="#FFFFF500"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <RadioButton GroupName="Os" Content="Storyboard 1" IsChecked="True" FontSize="16" Margin="10,10,10,0"/>
    <RadioButton GroupName="1" Content="Storyboard 2" Margin="10,31,0,0" FontSize="16" />
    <RadioButton GroupName="1" Content="Storyboard 3" Margin="10,50,0,0" FontSize="16" />
    <Button x:Name="Next" Content="Next&gt;" Width="75.06" Height="23" IsDefault="True" 
            Click="ClickNextButton" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
            Width="100" Background="Red"/>
</Grid>
```

C#:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void ClickNextButton(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e) 
    { 
        Counter += 1; 
        if (Counter == 1) { } 
        if (Counter == 2) { } 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put your `Storyboards` inside a [`VisualStateManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visualstatemanager.aspx) you can use the [`GoToState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991369.aspx) method:

```
VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Storyboard1", useTransitions);
```

Your XAML will become something like this:

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup Name="MyStates">
        <VisualState Name="Storyboard1">
            <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red"/>
                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="#FF00FFED"/>
                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
             </Storyboard>
          </VisualState>
          ....
    </VisualStateGroup>
  </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Note that the name has moved from the `Storyboard` to a `VisualState`.

Your code behind is then something like this:

```
    if (Counter == 1)
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Storyboard1", useTransitions);
    } 
    if (Counter == 2)
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Storyboard2", useTransitions);
    }
```

(Though this is from memory so there might be syntax errors)